# ArgumentError : Could not determind dialect for 'sqllite'. (database error)

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask

I am following this particular blog which explain flask very well.

http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database

I create database file and I try to run them by

> ./db_create.py

I get various errors.

Will upload the picture for convenience. 
[image]

Comment: It seems `sqlite` is misspelled.

Comment: Don't upload an image when you can copy and paste the actual text instead.

Answer (score 4):

It should be **sqlite** you have **sqllite**

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @ChrisBallard: actually, this is a correct answer to the question. The connection string is misspelled.

Comment: Apologies, looks like I read this too quickly.

Answer (score 3):

You misspelled `sqlite`; it has only *one* `l`.